# Can I configure DotNetOpenAuth request token expiration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, dotnetopenauth, oauth-provider

In our API we implemented DotNetOpenAuth (v3.4.7).
We frequently receive the exception "A token in the message was not recognized by the service provider", along with this stack trace:

```
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.ThrowProtocol(String message, Object[] args)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.TokenHandlingBindingElement.VerifyThrowTokenTimeToLive(ITokenContainingMessage message)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.ChannelElements.TokenHandlingBindingElement.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ProcessIncomingMessage(IProtocolMessage message)
```

Just recently I discovered this exception is thrown when people take too long authorize their request token. So the time between step 1 and step 2 of the authorization process is too long.

Can this time be configured in the web.config or programmatically?

Note: I tried `messaging lifetime="00:30:00"` but that does not seem to influence what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two factors go into possibly producing this error:

1. `IServiceProviderTokenManager.GetRequestToken` throws a `KeyNotFoundException`, OR
2. The token is older than the timeout specified in your web.config file's `dotNetOpenAuth/oauth/serviceProvider/security/@maxAuthorizationTime` setting.

For example:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <oauth>
        <serviceProvider>
            <security maxAuthorizationTime="00:05:00"/>
        </serviceProvider>
    </oauth>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

Comment: Factor 2 was my problem. Thanks a lot for answering. Keep up the good work on your library. Hope to update to v4 very soon.

Comment: I tried putting this info in my web.config file, but no changes to the expires_in time...it still shows the same value (in my case 3600).